# python-Dataframe: How to iterate over index rows?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I want to iterate over all the index rows of my first dataframe.
And if this index exists in the indexes of the second dataframe, I want to return this line.

I see that `df1.loc[2]` returns the data in the row where the index is 2.

How can I iterate over all of the indexes in both dataframes?

Comment: `result = df2[df2.index.isin(df1.index)]`

Comment: `df1.loc[df1.index.intersection(df2.index)]`

Comment: it works thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.join` between dataframes to get the rows with same indexes.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd 
...: a = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 3]}, index=[1, 2])                                                                                                 
...:  
...: b = pd.DataFrame({'b': [3, 4]}, index=[2, 5]) 
...: a.join(b, how='inner')                                                                                                                        
Out[1]: 
   a  b
2  3  3
```